# strange selection of events with TYPO3 extension calendarize

Tags: typo3, typo3-9.x

I have a problem with ext:calendarize 6.0.0 in TYPO3 9.5.22:

in my dev-system my day-listings are off by one day:
all events from 14.10.2020 are shown on the next day (15.10.) with correct date in the preview.

After deploying from dev to test system the behaviour changed:
while on the dev-system the events have an offset of one day precise, on the test-system some events are not listed at all in the day-view.

Other views (list, year, month, week) show the events on the correct day.

It's always the day-view which has strange behaviour.
Is there a problem with the query?
I suspect defect timezone handling. **Do I need some configuration or corrections for clean handling?**

Comment: It might be different due to different system locales in conjunction with inrobust date handling in the extension. A day off could for example be caused by different timezones.

Comment: both instances are on the same server. so the same timezone (berlin). as said: i suspect timezones miscalculation, but why do they behave different ? and why are some events missing at all (not on the wrong day, they are lost completely in day view) in test system?